# How to make calls to google-cloud/local-auth from a NodeJS server thats being hosted in a Docker Container?

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

I have a NodeJS server that I was planning on deploying, so I dockerized it to make that process easier. I am now running into a problem where every time I try to authenticate or obtain a users refresh token for their google account, it won't run. I assume this is because it's in a docker container which is an isolated process and cannot open a tab in Chrome to allow access for my server to get the token. But this brings me to the question, why is there a library for NodeJS servers to gain access to google cloud, if they cannot authenticate from a purely server-side standpoint? I am probably missing something here but I have been pulling teeth out over this one.

```
async function authorize() {
    let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (client) {
        return client;
    }
    client = await authenticate({
        scopes: SCOPES,
        keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });
    if (client.credentials) {
        await saveCredentials(client);
    }
    return client;
}
```

Here is my authorize function that I would use to obtain all the necessary credentials to make calls to the GmailAPI for any given user. The main thing that I need to obtain from this is the refresh token. This is once again in a docker container running locally for now.

For more Context, this was the flow before I dockerized: a user would have the chrome extension, then upon clicking it, it would pop up with the Google OAuth2.0 prompt to give us access to their token. We can then use this to make calls to the Gmail API for any given user that we have. We are just modifying emails/labeling them for a better ease of use.

I thought I could make a call on the client-side(this is a chrome extension), to obtain the refresh token, but have run into countless CORS errors. I also do not want to expose the ClientID of my Google Cloud. I thought maybe we could get a token from the client, and pass it to the server and get the refresh token that way, but nothing seems to be working. I also do not want to be handling user refresh tokens on the client side of things as it seems a little risky to me- but any suggestions would be awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Alright after multiple hours I hope this will make sense to some people. Basically everything I found online told me to use a service account to get this done, however when you look at the use cases for those its the opposite of what I actually needed to be done. On my client-side(chrome extension) I was able to run the user through the authorization process, and then pass that temporary token to the backend, where a few more calls are made to find the refresh token. Alls thats really needed for the `google-cloud/local-auth` to run properly is that token, as the rest of the things are always the same and can be handled by me. Weirdly the solution I found to this was posted recently but has very little views, so it took some digging! Feeling pretty lucky about it right now. Thank you all and hopefully this can help others out in the future. Its always a learning process!

Here is the link to the medium article, I wish it had more traction as it's the only one that i've found to actually contain useful information in a clear and concise way.

https://medium.com/@tony.infisical/guide-to-using-oauth-2-0-to-access-google-apis-dead94d6866d